# Decodeable SWIFT parsing Rest API data error

Tags: arrays, swift, rest, dictionary, decodable

I am trying to query the marvel API. I believe my decodable is wrong. I have the following code:

```
struct ReturnedData : Decodable {
    
    var id : Int?
    var name : String?
    var description : String?
}

var savedData : [ReturnedData] = []
    
    let urlString = "https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=\(myAPIKey)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let recievedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([ReturnedData].self, from: data)
            self.savedData = recievedData
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

I am getting the following error message:
*typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))*

according to the documentation, I should get all of the below:
Character

**id** (int, optional): The unique ID of the character resource.,
**name** (string, optional): The name of the character.
**description** (string, optional): A short bio or description of the character.
**modified** (Date, optional): The date the resource was most recently modified.
**resourceURI** (string, optional): The canonical URL identifier for this resource.
**urls** (Array[Url], optional): A set of public web site URLs for the resource.
**thumbnail** (Image, optional): The representative image for this character.
**comics** (ComicList, optional): A resource list containing comics which feature this character.
**stories** (StoryList, optional): A resource list of stories in which this character appears
**events** (EventList, optional): A resource list of events in which this character appears.
**series** (SeriesList, optional): A resource list of series in which this character appears.

Also, any tips on how to get the thumbnail image is appreciated.

Comment: Read the JSON at the end of the URL. You need to pass a few levels before having your `ReturnedData`: `topLevel["data"]["results"]` (in pseudo code).

Comment: In the doc https://developer.marvel.com/docs#!/public/getCreatorCollection_get_0, it's stated , it's stated: first `CharacterDataWrapper`, that will have a `CharacterDataContainer`at `data`, then that `CharacterDataContainer` will have an array of `Character` at `results`.

Comment: If that API Key is private/personal, remove it from the question for privacy purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because the model you have does not match the json data. So, try this approach `...to query the marvel API...`.
In future, copy and paste your json data into https://app.quicktype.io/
this will generate the models for you. Adjust the resulting code to your needs. Alternatively read the docs at: https://developer.marvel.com/docs#!/public/getCreatorCollection_get_0 and create the models by hand from the info given.

```
class MarvelModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var results = [MarvelResult]()
    
    let myAPIKey = "xxxx"
    let myhash = "xxxx"
    
    func getMarvels() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=\(myAPIKey)&hash=\(myhash)") else { return }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(MarvelResponse.self, from: data)
            Task{@MainActor in
                results = response.data.results
            }
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = MarvelModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if vm.results.isEmpty { ProgressView() }
            List(vm.results) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
        .task {
            await vm.getMarvels()
        }
    }
}

struct MarvelResponse: Decodable {
    let code: Int
    let status, copyright, attributionText, attributionHTML: String
    let etag: String
    let data: MarvelData
}

struct MarvelData: Decodable {
    let offset, limit, total, count: Int
    let results: [MarvelResult]
}

struct MarvelResult: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name, resultDescription: String
    let modified: String
    let thumbnail: Thumbnail
    let resourceURI: String
    let comics, series: Comics
    let stories: Stories
    let events: Comics
    let urls: [URLElement]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case resultDescription = "description"
        case modified, thumbnail, resourceURI, comics, series, stories, events, urls
    }
}

struct Comics: Decodable {
    let available: Int
    let collectionURI: String
    let items: [ComicsItem]
    let returned: Int
}

struct ComicsItem: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    let resourceURI: String
    let name: String
}

struct Stories: Decodable {
    let available: Int
    let collectionURI: String
    let items: [StoriesItem]
    let returned: Int
}

struct StoriesItem: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    let resourceURI: String
    let name: String
    let type: String
}

struct Thumbnail: Decodable {
    let path: String
    let thumbnailExtension: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case path
        case thumbnailExtension = "extension"
    }
}

struct URLElement: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    let type: String
    let url: String
}
```

EDIT-1: if you want something very basic, then try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results = [MarvelResult]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(results) { item in
            Text(item.name)
        }
        .onAppear {
            getMarvels()
        }
    }
    
    func getMarvels() {
        let myAPIKey = "xxxx"
        let myhash = "xxxx"
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=\(myAPIKey)&hash=\(myhash)") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(MarvelResponse.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.results = response.data.results
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll have to play with this tomorrow. Thank you for the comprehensive answer although you seem to use many more complex protocols than I want. I'm trying to keep it simple and your code looks quite complex.

Comment: ok, I understand, see my updated answer (EDIT-1)

Comment: why do you have so many structs? What's confusing me most is I thought I only needed 1 struct for the data?

Comment: Also, you use "codable" for your structs, I had decodable... However it has worked for previous Rest API's I've done so I'm surprised.

Comment: you need those different models to correctly map the json data to those structs. This is what is required. You can replace all `Codable` with `Decodable`, and my code will still work. I have updated my answer with using only `Decodable`. `Codable` is use to encode **and** decode the models. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable

Comment: A few questions. 1: On some structs you have "Identifiable" why only on some?

Comment: Also, I've never seen this "Task" before, what does it accomplish? Task{@MainActor in

Comment: Finally, why the 3 enumeration levels? I assumed it would enumerate over the data types     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case resultDescription = "description"
        case modified, thumbnail, resourceURI, comics, series, stories, events, urls
    }

Comment: `Identifiable` makes it easier to use in SwiftUI, e.g. in `ForEach` or `List` loop, no need for the `id: .\self`.
I added this to those structs that are elements in an array, since this is where you may want to loop over. 

I declare them `let id = UUID()`, so they will not be "decoded" by the JSONDecoder. Alternatively, 
you can omit `id` from the CodingKeys. See : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable for an explanation.

Comment: Using `Task{@MainActor in ...` is just a way to have the enclosed code run on the main thread. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor  for a more formal explanation. 
This is part of the broader topic of Swift async/await concurrency.  
see for example: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132 . This is why I provided a more basic approach in `EDIT-1`.
Don't know what you mean by `...why the 3 enumeration levels`. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder 
for how json data is turned into a set of model structs.

Comment: At the top, @Published var results = [MarvelResult]().  Why the at-published and why the "()" at the end? What does that do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248162/discussion-between-mason-ballowe-and-workingdog-support-ukraine).

Comment: also the line (data, _) what is the underscore?

Comment: I think you really need to read the basics of Swift at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html  
and do the SwiftUi tutorial at https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/. These will explain and answer your questions, 
better than I can in the restricted space of a comment. If my answer was useful, could you mark it as accepted please. See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app for an explanation of `@Published`.